# How to mock Map with testng and powermockito

Tags: java, testng

For personMap, I am setting the values with Powermockito;

But I am unable to get the values from map;

```
/**
 * 
 */
package mapmoocer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class PersonStore {

    Map<String, java.util.List<Person>> personMap = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();


    public void check() {
        List<Person> list = personMap.get("RAM");
        for(Person person : list) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

Here, is the test class;
for `test_check()`, not able to cover for each block; 
`when(personMap.get("RAM")).thenReturn(value);` always returning empty; even though I am setting the values for map;

```
/**
 * 
 */
package mapmoocer;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class PersonTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PersonStore personStore = new PersonStore();

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    @Mock
    Map<String, java.util.List<Person>> personMap;

    @BeforeClass
    public void before(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void after() {

    }


    @Test
    public void test_hello() {
        personStore.hello();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_check() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setEmail("aa");
        java.util.List<Person> value = new ArrayList<Person>();
        when(personMap.get("RAM")).thenReturn(value);
        personStore.check();
    }

}
```

Help me on this.

Comment: for a moment just forget about test, does it work (production code), how do you set values to the map?

Comment: @hunter, thanks for reply; but intention is; how to mock map?

Comment: ok , if you are doing this only for learning purpose, then you have to use @Inject annotation for the field personMap in the PersonStore class. otherwise Mockitoanotations.initmock has no idea to inject that mocked instance to your personStore object

Comment: @hunter, @Inject/@InjectMocks?

Comment: it should be @Inject, it is in the production code.

Comment: Seriously: dont use PowerMock(ito) until you have to. Mockito does the job good enough. The additional features that PowerMock(ito) offers you are most often only required when you wrote "hard to test code". Beyond that: you dont learn such things from trying. Get good tutorials, and read them step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to mock a map? you can just create a new Map and assign it to your object. When we say `Mock` we `Mock` the action not the data.

We provide a mock is to make sure that the object we use will always provide a consistent value when we call one of its methods.

This will make us focus on the code we test, and don't need to worry about the method your code rely on will give you the wrong result.

So if you use a Map in your code, you just put the data in to the map, it's done. You don't need to mock it at all.

Comment: thanks for reply; while writing test cases; we have to make sure that, every method has to be cover; in this problem, main class has map as instance variable; so how to mock it?

Comment: @Creator It should be covered when you create the object. This code will be run when every time you create and object.

Comment: map object will create every time, agreed. how to push the values and test?

Comment: @Creator I do still not quite understand, why do you need to test a Map interface when it's an object of a build-in class. Don't tell me that you want to cover all the JVM code too.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to cover for-each snippet with the following code:

```
package mapmoocer;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class PersonTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PersonStore personStore = new PersonStore();

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    @Mock
    Map<String, java.util.List<Person>> personMap;

    @BeforeClass
    public void before(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void after() {

    }


    @Test
    public void test_hello() {
        personStore.hello();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="store")
    public void test_check(Object data) {
        java.util.List<Person> persons = (java.util.List<Person>)data;
        when(personMap.get("RAM")).thenReturn(persons);
        personStore.check();
    }

    public Object[][] store() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setEmail("aa");
        person.setName("AA");

        java.util.List<Person> value = new ArrayList<Person>();
        value.add(person);

        Object[][] result = {
                {value}
        };
        return result;
    }

}
```